# POST form displaying wrong echo

Tags: php, html, css, session

I'm trying to display one of two buttons depending on "magnum"(printername) being in present in the array "booleans".

My problem is that when the form gets posted, the data retrieved on page load is correct, but the buttons displayed are incorrect. if clicked on a button, the form posts and refreshes the page, "magnum" gets pushed into `$_SESSION['booleans']` but the button still displays `"btn btn-default"`, so it requires another page refresh for the button to load correctly(`'btn btn-succes'`).

Is my problem due to `$_SESSION` or am i missing something?

```
echo'
<form class="form1" method="post" action="" id="form1">
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2">';

if(in_array('magnum', $_SESSION['printers'])){
    if(in_array('magnumBool',$_SESSION['booleans'])){
        echo '<input type="submit" name="unSubmitMagnum" id="magnumBool" value="magnum" class='.$enabled_printer.'>';
        if(isset($_POST['unSubmitMagnum']) && $_POST['unSubmitMagnum']){
            $pos = array_search('magnumBool', $_SESSION['booleans']);
            unset($_SESSION['booleans'][$pos]);
            dump('unset');
        }
    }
    elseif(!in_array('magnumBool',$_SESSION['booleans'])){
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submitMagnum" id="magnumBool" value="magnum" class='.$disabled_printer.'>';
        if(isset($_POST['submitMagnum'])&& $_POST['submitMagnum']){
            array_push($_SESSION['booleans'],'magnumBool');
            dump('set');
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo '<button id="magnum" class='.$lost_connection_printer.'>1. Magnum</button>';
    }

echo ' 
</div>
</form>';
```

`$_SESSION['printers']` is an array containing "magnum" - 
`$_SESSION['booleans']` is the array which isn't working as i would like it to -

```
$enabled_printer = "btn btn-success" <br>
$disabled_printer = "btn btn-default" <br>
$lost_connection_printer = "btn btn-danger disabled"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing elaboration and printing. Try to split you code, so it will work and it will be more readable:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['unSubmitMagnum']) && $_POST['unSubmitMagnum']) {
        $pos = array_search('magnumBool', $_SESSION['booleans']);
        unset($_SESSION['booleans']['magnumBool']);
    } elseif (isset($_POST['submitMagnum'])&& $_POST['submitMagnum']) {
        $_SESSION['booleans']['magnumBool'] = true;
    }
}

echo'<form class="form1" method="post" action="" id="form1">
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2">';

if(in_array('magnum', $_SESSION['printers'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['booleans']['magnumBool'])){
        echo '<input type="submit" name="unSubmitMagnum" id="magnumBool" value="magnum" class='.$enabled_printer.'>';
    } else {
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submitMagnum" id="magnumBool" value="magnum" class='.$disabled_printer.'>';
    }
}
else{
    echo '<button id="magnum" class='.$lost_connection_printer.'>1. Magnum</button>';
}

echo '</div>
</form>';
```

P.s. note the use of "magnumBool" as a key isset instead of as a value: in this way (when possible) you will avoid duplicate entry and will make you code lighter if you have large arrays ;)

P.p.s. try always to keep you login separate from you template, this will make your code more readable and easier to maintain

Comment: Thanks a bunch! works as envisioned! mucho many kudo's to you! :)

Comment: happy to help :)